# When should I put state in parent?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, refactoring

**This is my first StackOverflow question**, feel free to add any suggestion you want.

I have an AudioControls component that renders four different Controls components, each for a different audio option (volume, bass, mid, treble).
I wrote it in a way that the parent knows and manage the four of the states:
useState({
volume: 50,
bass: 50,
mid: 50,
treble: 50,
})
and then passed these values to children as props.

I have two concerns regarding this:

1. Control components are simply the same and maybe they could have their own value state (put an audioValue state on each Control). I've read it's a good practice to always lift the state when possible, but why is it needed? What are good reasons to do it?
2. Is there a way to use the map function with these Controls given that they are all pretty similar? Without losing legibility, of course.

This is the AudioControl code:

```
function AudioControls() {
const [audioValues, setAudioValues] = useState({
    volume: 50,
    bass: 50,
    mid: 50,
    treble: 50
})

function handleControl(option, id) {
    const oldValue = audioValues[id]
    const newValue = option === "+" ? oldValue + 1 : oldValue - 1
    
    setAudioValues(prevState => (
        {
            ...prevState,
            [`${id}`] : newValue
        }
    ))
}

return(
    <>
        <Control
            id="volume"
            name="Volume"
            value={audioValues.volume}
            handleControl={handleControl}
        />
        <Control
            id="bass"
            name="Bass"
            value={audioValues.bass}
            handleControl={handleControl}
        />
        <Control
            id="mid"
            name="Mid"
            value={audioValues.mid}
            handleControl={handleControl}
        />
        <Control
            id="treble"
            name="Treble"
            value={audioValues.treble}
            handleControl={handleControl}
        />
    </>
   )
}
```

And here's the Control component:

```
function Control({ id, name, value, handleControl }) {
    return(
        <div>
            <button onClick={() => handleControl("+", id)}>
                +
            </button>
            <label>{name}: {value}</label>
            <button onClick={() => handleControl("-", id)}>
                -
            </button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This is my second stack overflow answer**. Also open to any and all feedback.

I'd be curious to learn where you heard the fact that it's always a good idea to lift state. My thought on that is: *if it's always a good idea to lift state, when do you stop lifting?* Why just move state up one in this case? Why not lift it even further?

To answer your first question: the main reason to lift state into a parent component is if you need two sibling components to use the same piece of state. For example:

```
const [volume, setVolume] = setState(50);

function changeVolume (newVolume) {
  setVolume(newVolume);
}

<VolumeDisplay volume={volume} />
<VolumeControl onChange={changeVolume} />
```

In your case, it looks like each one is capable of changing its own state so it's preferred to push state down to each `<Control>`. Once you put the audio value locally inside the control component you could map them easily like this:

```
const controls = [
  {id: "bass", name: "Bass"},
  {id: "volume", name: "Volume"},
  {id: "mid", name: "Mid"},
  {id: "treble", name: "Treble"},
]

return (
  <>
    {controls.map(({id, name}) => <Control id={id} name={name} />)}
  <>
)
```

Comment: Thank you! That way code looks cleaner.
I'm learning React using a book called "Pure React", and at some point, it says it's always better to keep components stateless so they are easier to maintain. It uses the example of a sidebar, and claims that if it needs to be hidden, show/hidden state should be lifted up, so it doesn't internally know whether it's visible and just be rendered or not (the advantage is that if you've got multiple sidebars and need to, say, save their state in local storage, you wouldn't need an additional way to differentiate them). But I'm probably mixing it all up :/